# BadParcelableException when reading from Android bundle

Tags: android

I am getting BadParcelableException when reading a String from the bundle. This happens only on the release version of APK.

I have added these rules on proguard-rules.pro, but still getting the same error.

**proguard-rules.pro**

```
-keepnames class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
    public static final ** CREATOR;
```

}

**Stacktrace for the error:**

```
Process: com.sample.app, PID: 15083                                                       android.os.BadParcelableException: Parcelable protocol requires a Parcelable.Creator object called  CREATOR on class com.sample.checkout.j
                                                           at android.os.Parcel.readParcelableCreator(Parcel.java:2304)
                                                           at android.os.Parcel.readParcelable(Parcel.java:2245)
                                                           at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2152)
                                                           at android.os.Parcel.readListInternal(Parcel.java:2526)
                                                           at android.os.Parcel.readArrayList(Parcel.java:1842)
                                                           at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2173)
                                                           at android.os.Parcel.readArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:2485)
                                                           at android.os.BaseBundle.unparcel(BaseBundle.java:221)
                                                           at android.os.BaseBundle.get(BaseBundle.java:280)
                                                           at com.sample.mp.checkout.SampleService.a(Unknown Source)
                                                           at com.sample.mp.checkout.t$1.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Any help on what could be causing this error?

Answer (score 0):

Resolved by adding @SerializedName annotation to the object variables.